Java Application REST Transactions are not showing in kibana,Elastic APM
My application is java(Spring boot)  which REST API transaction. When configured it to elastic APM..I can see metrics. But can not see REST API transaction to kibana/elastic search?
How can it get display in kibana ? Dosa it has any flag to enable and detect rest API calls ?
The configuration made with server_url, token and other details.
Tried by making sample rate to 1.0.
